xinput touchscreen transform matrix with cropped resolution
I'm having some trouble understanding how the xinput transformation matrix of a touchscreen (Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen) works.
I'm using a tablet with Linux installed to control a remote PC via ssh-rdp. The resolution of the remote PC is 1920x1080, and the native resolution of the tablet is 2160x1440. When changing the resolution of the tablet to 1920x1080, the image fills the entire width but not the entire height; it gets cropped above and below. The issue is that the touchscreen xinput coordinates continue to use the entire screen; vertically, they are correct at the center but misalign towards the upper or lower edge.
I thought that scaling the height using the matrix, scaling the height and offsetting y, or even just offsetting y, would be sufficient, but all the attempts I've made have given me inconsistent results (completely misaligned pointer).
Apparently, I'm missing something about how the matrix should be used to remap the coordinates. What I'm interested in is ignoring the cropped area and mapping the vertical coordinates 180-1260 to 0-1080, or alternatively offsetting the Y by 180, so native 180 become 0.
I tried xinput_calibrator, which theoretically supports xinput with --output-type but it actually gives me an error XorgPrint Calibrator does not support the supplied --output-type, Error: unable to apply or save configuration values. I'm not interested in an Xorg config; I want to be able to change the matrix with a script. Are there any other GUI tools that can generate the correct matrix to use with xinput?
svelte repl

Edit:

